# Generating Method Call Diagram in Java Project

Tags: java, trace, auto-generate

I have a source code of a java Project and i want to trace for every method, what method called inside that method.

example:

```
foo(){}
bar(){}
bar2(){
   bar();
}
foo2(){
   bar();
   bar2();
}

main(){
   foo2();
}
```

the result will be like:

```
main
|_foo2
  |_bar
  |_bar2
    |_bar
```

any add-ons or plug-ins is okay and since it is an internal project of a company, i hope the tools is offline. For the result, it doesn't have to be like that, graph or anything is okay.

Adding some information:

1. I cannot edit the code
2. I cannot run the code
3. but (maybe) i can add them to eclipse IDE
4. The project is either in WAR, EAR, or JAR type

Comment: Are you able to chage code of these methods?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, If you are use Eclipse as your IDE, then you can right click on a method and choose "open call hierarchy"
then eclipse shows all the methods that call the selected method and all the methods that are called from the selected method .

Secondly We can find it by programming.

ie, by using the eclipse JDT internal classes, these are the same classes used by eclipse to show whose calling the method.

initially we need to importing below two classes,

```
    import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.callhierarchy.CallHierarchy;

    import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.callhierarchy.MethodWrapper;
```

And then Create a method to get callers, and  that takes the selected method as an input.(please note it will be your API type method) you should call this method from your program for find which methods call what..

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a pure Java project with no other framework, one way to do this would be to use AspectJ to intercept every method, and put an entry in Thread local map for method name to counter + 1. If `main` is 0, `foo2` would be 1, `bar` and `bar2` would be 2, and so on.
See [this section](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-development.html#tracing) of AspectJ docs.

Comment: the main problem is i cannot run the code

Answer (score 0):

- All you need is to use `ajc` compiler instead of `javac`. It makes you able to use `AspectJ`. Using aspects you can define `Pointcut` and log what you need.
- Another option I think, could be analyze a stacktrase after all calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Plugin like **Code Iris** from IntelliJ

Comment: Code Iris provides graph right, but when i see it, the graph look very complicated hahah

Comment: Code Iris is useful when you are dealing with a large code base.                              
For "hello world", you can use Eclipse as your IDE, then you can right click on a method and choose "open call hierarchy". This can serve your purpose.  There are other software like "Source Insight" that will also serve your purpose.

Comment: is it okay if the source code is in jar or ear or something else?